# Execution error when mapping from a MongoDB embedded document

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo, reactivemongo-play-json

Suppose I am trying to output an embedded field from a *mongoDB* (using the *Play Framework 2.6* - in JSON). A typical document looks like this:

```
   _id : ObjectId("66bc9c788c788cafdb053a23"),
   name : "Name game"
   myFieldArr : [
     {
        fieldName : "A playing field"
        fieldGroup: "Landscape"
        numOfGroup: 22
     },
     ...
   ]
```

I am using [$unwind from the Aggregation Framework in reactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/advanced-topics/aggregation.html#unwind) so I have this:

```
  def getAggregate(col: JSONCollection) = {

    import col.BatchCommands.AggregationFramework.{UnwindField}

    col.aggregate(UnwindField("myFieldArr")).map(_.head[MyAggregate])

  }
```

I have a case class which I am [automatically mapping to the mongoDB documents with Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated):

```
   case class MyField(fieldName: String, fieldGroup: String, numOfGroup: Int) {

   case class MyAggregate(_id: Option[BSONObjectID], name: String, myField: MyField) {
     def idAsBsonId = _id.get
     def idAsString = idAsBsonId.stringify
   }
```

But I keep getting this error:

> [JsResultException:
>   JsResultException(errors:List((/myField,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))]

I've been through a bunch of [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737897/play-scalajson-readst-parsing-validationerrorerror-path-missing-wrappedarray) but none for the purpose of mapping from a mongoDB document so I can't quite get this right. Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: First execute the same in MongoShell (and see that there is no expected `myField`)

Comment: @cchantep. Thanks - this seems like a while back and I have since resolved the issue that I was having. I tend to initially test in the Mongo Shell and then write the reactiveMongo scala code. I believe that the issue was that one of the parameters in the case class that I was using to map to the Mongo documents was called `myField` rather than `myFieldArr` - at least as far as I recall. I'm finding that nowadays not many of my questions are answered here - you are one of the few that take the time to do that - so thanks!